# HTTP unsupported Media type issue

Tags: ios, wcf, http, iis

i use WCF with ios application, and when request for some method, IIS returns me 415 error, Not Supported Media Type.
Proxy class are generated through wsdl2objc, the same call from windows application works fine

Comment: can you show some code where you think the issue maybe?

Comment: i have no idea where it might happen, request headers for both applications the same,the only difference was request content type, for ios it was text/xml , and for win app it is application/soap+msbin1. i change the the contenttype for ios and set it to application/soap+xml, because when it is application/soap+msbin1  IIS returns me status 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in your WCF service configuration, specifically the binding you're using. I suppose you have configured it to use either custom binding or `WSHttpBinding`, but in either way the service expects `application/soap+msbin1` mime type, but the requests made by the generated classes from wsdl2objc are with `text/xml`. I'm not quite sure how to fix it, but start by configuring your service for the standard `BasicHttpBinding` and give it a try. Also revert all changes you've made on the generated code from wsdl2objc.
Btw `WSHttpBinding` uses SOAP 1.2 and I'm not sure if `wsdl2objc` can work with it (i have tested it only with `BasicHttpBinding`).

Comment: thanks graver, as i understand wsdl2objc doesn't support custom bindings right? my service configured with custom bindings, i use it for authentication ticket. In that case is there any way to configure binding in basichttpbinding for authentication ? i'm not sure about wshttpbinding too, when i used asmx services with wsdl2objc it generates soap12 client also, but i never used it.